# Given a tangential quadrilateral with all angles known, determine the area and perimeter

Tags: geometry

> We have a tangential quadrilateral whose all angles are known and whose inradius is known. Can we have a general expression for the perimeter/area  of the quadrilateral in given variables?

I can find it out for individual cases, but not getting a generalized expression.

[image]

$$a = ? \qquad b=? \qquad c=?  \qquad d=?$$

Comment: Connect the incenter to the vertices and the points of tangency. You'll find lots of right triangles, each with a known side and a known acute angle. From these, it's straightforward to determine the perimeter and area of the quadrilateral.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=\overline{AB}$, $b=\overline{BC}$, $c=\overline{CD}$, $d=\overline{DA}$,

$\alpha=\angle{DAB}$, $\beta=\angle{ABC}$, $\gamma=\angle{BCD}$, $\delta=\angle{CDA}$,

$A_c$, $B_c$, $C_c$, $D_c$, are the points where the sides $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ touch the incircle respectively

and $r$ be the inradius.

Then $$a= \overline{AA_c}+\overline{A_cB}$$
$$\overline{AA_c}=r\cdot cot(\frac{\alpha}{2})$$
$$\overline{A_cB}=r\cdot cot(\frac{\beta}{2})$$
$$a=r\cdot \bigl( cot(\frac{\alpha}{2})+cot(\frac{\beta}{2})\bigr)$$
simmilar steps for the other sides

EDIT: fixed the angel functions as mentioned in the comments